# Spring Data Redis Reactive: StreamReceiver to coroutines Flow

Tags: spring-data-redis-reactive

I'm writing an app that works with Redis Stream using Spring Data Redis. I'm using `spring-data-redis` with Lettuce. I can successfully write to the stream as I can validate it directly in Redis via redis-cli, and I see the messages are in Redis. When it comes to reading from the stream using `StreamReceiver`, it kind of works but my tests fail for the coroutines version.

So, I've implemented two versions for reading with different return types:

- `Flux<TestData>`. I test it using `reactor-test` classes, similar to what Spring Data Redis team does. It works fine: received items are printed out and test passes.
- `Flow<TestData>`. I test it using FlowTurbine. This tests fails, even though the received items are printed out; FlowTurbine just times out. I tried using directly blocking `Flow.toList()` instead of Turbine's `test`, but in this case the call just blocks forever. I'm probably doing something wrong, when I deal with the Flow. What am I doing wrong? And how to fix it?

`TestDataRedisRepository.kt` content:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.FlowPreview
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.flatMapConcat
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.map
import kotlinx.coroutines.reactive.asFlow
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.stream.MapRecord
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.stream.RecordId
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.stream.StreamOffset
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.stream.StreamRecords
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.ReactiveRedisTemplate
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.addAndAwait
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.trimAndAwait
import org.springframework.data.redis.stream.StreamReceiver
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux

const val STREAM_KEY = "test-data"

@Repository
class TestDataRedisRepository(
    val reactiveRedisTemplate: ReactiveRedisTemplate<String, TestData>,
    val streamReceiver: StreamReceiver<String, MapRecord<String, String, String>>
) {
    private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this::class.java)

    @FlowPreview
    fun saveAll(entityStream: Flow<TestData>): Flow<RecordId> {
        return entityStream
            .map { toMapRecord(it) }
            .flatMapConcat {
                log.info("Saving record: $it")
                reactiveRedisTemplate
                    .opsForStream<String, TestData>()
                    .add(it)
                    .asFlow()
            }
    }

    suspend fun save(TestData: TestData): RecordId {
        val record = toMapRecord(TestData)
        log.info("Saving record: $record")
        return reactiveRedisTemplate
            .opsForStream<String, TestData>()
            .addAndAwait(record)
    }

    private fun toMapRecord(TestData: TestData): MapRecord<String, String, String> =
        StreamRecords.newRecord()
            .`in`(STREAM_KEY)
            .ofMap(TestData.toMap())

    fun readAllAsFlux(): Flux<TestData> {
        return streamReceiver
            .receive(StreamOffset.fromStart(STREAM_KEY))
            .doOnEach { log.info("Received stream record: $it") }
            .map { it.value.fromMap() }
    }

    fun readAllAsFlow(): Flow<TestData> {
        return streamReceiver
            .receive(StreamOffset.fromStart(STREAM_KEY))
            .doOnEach { log.info("Received stream record: $it") }
            .map { it.value.fromMap() }
            .asFlow()
    }

    suspend fun deleteAll() {
        reactiveRedisTemplate
            .opsForStream<String, TestData>()
            .trimAndAwait(STREAM_KEY, 0)
    }
}
```

Test class `TestDataRedisRepositoryTest.kt` content:

```
import app.cash.turbine.test
import kotlinx.coroutines.FlowPreview
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.flowOf
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.toList
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInstance
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import reactor.test.StepVerifier
import java.time.Duration
import java.time.Instant
import kotlin.time.ExperimentalTime

@FlowPreview
@ExperimentalTime
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@SpringBootTest
internal class TestDataRedisRepositoryTest @Autowired constructor(
    private val testDataRedisRepository: TestDataRedisRepository
) {
    private val now: Instant = Instant.now()

    @BeforeAll
    fun setUp() {
        runBlocking { testDataRedisRepository.deleteAll() }
    }

    @AfterEach
    fun afterEach() {
        runBlocking {
            testDataRedisRepository.deleteAll()
        }
    }

    @Test //passes
    fun `test Flux`() {
        runBlocking {
            testDataRedisRepository.saveAll(
                flowOf(
                    TestData(now.minusSeconds(1), "test2"),
                    TestData(now, "test3")
                )
            ).toList()
        }

        testDataRedisRepository.readAllAsFlux().`as`(StepVerifier::create) //
            .consumeNextWith {
                assertThat(it).isEqualTo(TestData(now.minusSeconds(1), "test2"))
            }
            .consumeNextWith {
                assertThat(it).isEqualTo(TestData(now, "test3"))
            }
            .thenCancel()
            .verify(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
    }

    @Test //fails
    fun `test Flow`() {
        runBlocking {
            testDataRedisRepository.saveAll(
                flowOf(
                    TestData(now.minusSeconds(1), "test2"),
                    TestData(now, "test3")
                )
            ).toList()

//            val list = testDataRedisRepository.readAllAsFlow().toList() // this call blocks forever

            // FlowTurbine just times out
            testDataRedisRepository.readAllAsFlow()
                .test {
                    assertThat(expectItem())
                        .isEqualTo(TestData(now.minusSeconds(1), "test2"))
                    assertThat(expectItem())
                        .isEqualTo(TestData(now, "test3"))

                    expectComplete()
                }
        }
    }
}
```

My `RedisConfig.kt` content:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.stream.MapRecord
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.ReactiveRedisTemplate
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.RedisSerializationContext
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.RedisSerializer
import org.springframework.data.redis.stream.StreamReceiver

@Configuration
class RedisConfig {

    /**
     * For writing to Redis Stream
     */
    @Bean
    fun reactiveRedisTemplate(
        factory: ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory,
        serializationContext: RedisSerializationContext<String, TestData>
    ): ReactiveRedisTemplate<String, TestData> = ReactiveRedisTemplate(
        factory,
        serializationContext
    )

    /**
     * For reading from Redis Stream
     */
    @Bean
    fun streamReceiver(
        factory: ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory,
        serializationContext: RedisSerializationContext<String, TestData>
    ): StreamReceiver<String, MapRecord<String, String, String>> {
        return StreamReceiver.create(
            factory,
            StreamReceiver.StreamReceiverOptions.builder()
                .serializer(serializationContext)
                .build()
        )
    }

    @Bean
    fun serializationContext(): RedisSerializationContext<String, TestData> =
        RedisSerializationContext.newSerializationContext<String, TestData>(
            RedisSerializer.string()
        ).build()
}
```

`TestData.kt`

```
import java.time.Instant

data class TestData(
    val instant: Instant,
    val content: String
)

const val INSTANT = "instant"
const val CONTENT = "content"

fun TestData.toMap(): Map<String, String> {
    return mapOf(
        INSTANT to instant.toString(),
        CONTENT to content
    )
}

fun Map<String, String>.fromMap(): TestData {
    return TestData(
        Instant.parse(this[INSTANT]),
        this[CONTENT]!!
    )
}
```

Redis is running in a Docker container on the default port.
For completeness, here are `aplication.yaml` and `build.gradle.kts`:

```
spring:
  redis:
    host: localhost
    port: 6379
```

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.5.2"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.20"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.5.20"
}

group = "com.example"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive")
    implementation("io.projectreactor.kotlin:reactor-kotlin-extensions")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor")

    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("io.projectreactor:reactor-test")
    testImplementation("app.cash.turbine:turbine:0.5.2")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the test needs to check multiple values then calling `toList()` causes the flow to wait for the source to emit all its values and then returns those values as a list. Note that this works only for finite data streams.

So, in your case if its a stream that emits infinite values then it will wait forever to collect the values which is why your test is blocked.

A solution can be to take a finite number of items from flow and then do the assertion. For example, you can do something like the code below:

```
// Take the first item and cancel the flow
val firstItem = testDataRedisRepository.readAllAsFlow().first()

// Take the second item
val secondItem = testDataRedisRepository.readAllAsFlow().drop(1).first()

// Take the first five items
val firstFiveItems = testDataRedisRepository.readAllAsFlow().take(5).toList()
```

For more scenarios, you can refer to this Android Developers [link](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/test) for testing Kotlin flow.

Comment: Suddenly help came from Android side :) I thought `toList()` additionally cancels the flow, but turns out it doesn't. Thanks for pointing that out. I also assumed that Turbine's `test()` cancels the flow, but this also is not the case, turned out.

Comment: Glad that it helped!